# Как привязать домен к Django

Tags: django, apache, nginx

Всем привет. Есть VPS на nginx + apache (+ispmanager)

Есть сайт django + oscar.

Заливаю архив сайта в то место куда указывает домен, выполняю команды
make libs
make install
servise uwsgi resrtart
servise nginx resrtart

Но по домену просто открывается содержимое этой папки http://aleol.ru/
Всё что удалось достичь, запустить сайт из этой же папки через ip + порт 805
http://5.45.121.227:805/

Для этого получается такой makefile

```
.PHONY: libs install start stop
NAME = chem
CTX = prod
PORT = 805
DOMAIN = 5.45.121.227

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = $(NAME).settings.$(CTX)
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

libs:
aptitude -y install python-pip python-dev build-essential python-virtualenv     libjpeg-dev daemon nginx uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-python git libmysqlclient-dev

virtualenv oscar
oscar/bin/pip install django-oscar==1.1.1 pysolr simplejson xlrd MySQL-           python 
oscar/bin/pip uninstall -y Pillow
oscar/bin/pip install Pillow

rm -rf solr-4.7.2
wget -q http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.7.2/solr-4.7.2.tgz -O solr-4.7.2.tgz   
tar xzf solr-4.7.2.tgz
mv solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf.original
mkdir solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf
cp -rp solr.conf/* solr-4.7.2/example/solr/collection1/conf
install:    
python confgen.py $(NAME) $(CTX) $(DOMAIN) $(PORT)

rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$(NAME)_nginx.conf
rm -rf /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/$(NAME)_uwsgi.ini

ln -s $(shell pwd)/$(NAME)_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ln -s $(shell pwd)/$(NAME)_uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/

chmod 744 solr.run  
chown -R www-data pid
chgrp -R www-data pid   
chown -R www-data logs
chgrp -R www-data logs
chown -R www-data $(NAME)/public
chgrp -R www-data $(NAME)/public

oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py migrate
oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata init
oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata flatpage
oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py loaddata offer
oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

chown -R www-data $(NAME)/public
chgrp -R www-data $(NAME)/public

static:
oscar/bin/python $(NAME)/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

start:  
./solr.run start
service uwsgi restart

stop:       
service uwsgi stop
./solr.run stop
```

а в файле настроек
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.aleol.ru', '5.45.121.227']

Подскажите, как привязать домен к сайту Django? Где копнуть?

Comment: если указать в make file DOMAIN = aleol.ru ситуация не поменяется.

Comment: Все правильно. Потому что у Вас стандартный порт для соединения - 80-й.  А для django Вы указали 805. Если открыть сайт как http://aleol.ru:805/ то все ОК Но это скорее всего неправильно. Поэтому нужно настроить nginx, чтобы он брал на себя сайт aleol.ru и редиректил запрос на django. При этом сам сайт на django ЛУЧШЕ сделать доступным только с локалхоста.
Причем тут апач - я так и не понял....

Comment: Про апач написал, для полноты, я в этом не силен, написал что знаю) Благодарю за ответ, стало немного яснее. Но как сделать пока не понимаю. Лучше всё-таки указать 80й порт? и как сделать, чтобы "редиректил запрос на django."?

Comment: если я указываю 80й порт черезе makefile и исполняю его, то сайт становиться недоступным ни через ip ни через домен

Comment: Правильно, потому что 80-й порт занят nginx'ом и apache'ем....

Comment: "редиректил запрос на django."

Прочитать толковый мануал. https://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/

Comment: прочитал... только если я захожу как там написано aleol.ru:80 я попадаю не на nginx а на апач - внизу написано Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at aleol.ru Port 80

Comment: привязываю apache на другой порт 8080 и все сайты начинаю открывать nginx - НО 502 Bad Gateway рестарты не помогают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем не знаю, можно ли считать это ответом, но мне помогла тех. поддержка

"Дело в том, что для сайта aleol.ru уже создана конфигурация в основном файле nginx.conf , поэтому вместо добавления дополнительной конфигурации имеет смысл поправить уже существующую.
Мы перенесли Вашу конфигурацию из файла ..."